# Why is the difference between a task_struct pointer and a field inside that struct so large?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, kernel

This statement:

```
pr_err("init=%p head=%p offset=%zd\n", 
        &init_task, &init_task.thread_group,
        offsetof(struct task_struct, thread_group));
```

produces this output when compiled into a kernel module and insmod'ed:

```
init=00000000b0561be0 head=00000000cab9146b offset=2416
```

My question is why are the two addresses so far apart when they should only be 2416 bytes apart ? When printing the symbol offsets in GDB, I also get expected values, and I'm not sure where else to look:

```
(gdb) p &init_task
$1 = (struct task_struct *) 0xffffffff82613780 <init_task>
(gdb) p &init_task.thread_group 
$2 = (struct list_head *) 0xffffffff826140f0 <init_task+2416>
```

EDIT: %zx instead of %p yields correct numbers. So, no %p support in printk() I guess ?

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt:

```
Pointers printed without a specifier extension (i.e unadorned %p) are
hashed to give a unique identifier without leaking kernel addresses to user
space. On 64 bit machines the first 32 bits are zeroed. If you _really_
want the address see %px below.
```